# Using log4net.dll and facing version difference

Tags: .net

I have added log4net in my project and it is giving me this error in local system as well as server. Can someone please tell me how to get rid of it?

> Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Answer (score 0):

If you added the reference via NuGet than the problem is probably that NuGet downloaded the new version, but one of the the projects referenced parts already uses an older version. This can also happen if you're referencing external projects that use the same assembly.

if there is a project in your solution, than the easiest way to manage that is to uninstall  log4net fron the new project (via NuGet), and then click on the solution, go to 'Manage NuGet packages', select installed packages, find log4net and click manage. You should see the projects uring log4net, and there will be checkboxes available fot projects that do not reference it. Select your new project to install  **the existing log4net version in this project**

Answer (score 0):

Check that the version in the config section is correct based on your installed version. If its different sometimes you get the error mentioned or silent failure at runtime.

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net, Version=2.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a"></section>
  </configSections>
```